# Symfony2 Doctrine bundle constructor, what is the $typesconfig requirement they are asking for?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle, dbal

Hey guys I'm trying to port the [ConnectionFactory](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/ConnectionFactory.php) class from the Symfony2 Doctrine2 bundle back into a stock installation of Doctrine2, but ran across a snag. The constructor requires an initialization array of `$typesconfig` on line 36. I briefly had a ticket open with FOS [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/194) but was told that this had nothing to do with the mime.magic. They did not go on to explain what the `$typesconfig` variable actually is though or why it is required.

In order to port this, I need to understand what the `$typesconfig` array is and what it holds, could someone please tell me what is in this constructor variable so I can finish porting this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dive into the [configuration of DoctrineBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/dbal.xml) and you will find what you're looking for.

There is a parameter `doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.class` which holds the ConnectionFactory classname.

This parameter is used to define the service `doctrine.dbal.connection` which receives the argument `%doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types%` - a parameter array aka the `typeConfigs`.

Now just search your vendor dir for `doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types` and you will find:

```
$container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types', $config['types']);
```

I leave the final step of finding `types` in [DoctrineBundle's configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) to you...

tip: it's somewhere around `doctrine.dbal.types` with a little description :)